# Using Bootstrap Colors in JS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-visualization

I am using a Google-Chart and want to set the slice colors to the color used by bootstrap, e.g., for `badge-success` or `badge-danger`. Is there any way to access these color-codes from within JavaScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works if you're using Bootstrap 4:

```
const root = document.querySelector('html');
getComputedStyle(root).getPropertyValue('--danger');
```

You can access the CSS variables present in the :root pseudoelement

Comment: Working nicely thanks. also tried `$('.badge-warning').css("backgroundColor")` which does the job too if I really need to access some specific class and CSS feature

Comment: Yes - but you'd need to have one of those badge-warning elements on every page where you have the chart.  Otherwise that jquery call will return undefined.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about that. That would've been quite a surprise. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 3):

Another approach is...

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<div id="myBadge" class="badge-danger"></div>';
var elem = document.getElementById("myBadge");
var dangerColor = window.getComputedStyle(elem).getPropertyValue("background-color");
elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/GC96hjbf5v